# How to rotate bits to the left and add rotated bits to the right

Tags: c, algorithm, rotation, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to get my program to work, where I shift bits to the left and add the shifted bits to the right. For example `00111000`, if you shift it 4 positions to the left, the outcome should be `10000011`. How can I make this work, I know that I need to use the bitwise OR. I have added the main function below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printbits(int b){
    int i;
    int s = 8 * (sizeof b) - 1; /* 31 if int is 32 bits */
    for(i=s;i>=0;i--)
    putchar( b & 1<<i ? '1' : '0');
}



int main(){
    char dir; /* L=left R=right */
    int val, n, i;

    scanf("%d %d %c",&val, &n, &dir);
    printbits(val);putchar('\n');
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    if (dir=='L' || dir =='l')
      rotateLeft(&val, n);
    else
      rotateRight(&val,n);      
    printbits(val); putchar('\n');
    }
return;
}
```

This is the rotateLeft en rotateRight function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rotateLeft(int *val, int N){
    int num = val[0];
    int pos = N;

    int result = num << pos;


}

void rotateRight(int *val, int N){
    int num = val[0];
    int pos = N;

    int result = num >> pos;


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this " add the shifted bits to the right"? Shift right and left then sum them?

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c). Note that if you're tossing about bits in the sign-bit of a signed `int`, you're walking on a pitch-black cliff edge with no flashlight.

Comment: @BenceKaulics if you shift it to the left 4 positions, those 1's should be added to the right. I have a hard time explaining, sorry :S

Comment: See  here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

Comment: @Sullivan No problem there, I should have understood it by your example.

Comment: Nitpick: Unless you know for a fact that the code will only ever run on systems with 8-bit bytes, you should multiply by `CHAR_BIT`, not `8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tested and non-optimized solution to complete your source code:

```
void rotateLeft(int *val, int N){
    unsigned int num = val[0];
    int pos = N;

    unsigned int part1 = num << pos;
    unsigned int part2 = (num >> ((sizeof(val[0])*CHAR_BIT)-pos));

    if (N != 0) {
        val[0] = part1 | part2;
    }
}

void rotateRight(int *val, int N){
    unsigned int num = val[0];
    int pos = N;

    unsigned int part1 = num >> pos;
    unsigned int part2 = (num << ((sizeof(val[0])*CHAR_BIT)-pos));

    if (N != 0) {
        val[0] = part1 | part2;
    }
}
```

> To prevent automatic carry during the shift right, you have to
>   consider value as unsigned int.

To prevent N = 0 interference, assign the result to the entry only when (N != 0). (See remark on post [ROL / ROR on variable using inline assembly in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387745/rol-ror-on-variable-using-inline-assembly-in-objective-c))

Comment: @piquard What does this part do? if (N != 0) {
        val[0] = part1 | part2;

Comment: @Sullivan the value in input is updated only when a ROR or ROL is ordered (meaning N != 0). NB: both two functions could be merge because a negative value for N will do the reverse operation.

Comment: I see and why do you need to OR part 1 and part 2?

Comment: @Sullivan sorry, I didn't explain enough. The part1 is the number shifted (Left or Right) but stuffed by 0 and the part2 is the lost bits shifted to take place in front of part1 stuffed bits. The final OR merges the to set of bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
MSB = (n >> (NUM_OF_BITS_IN_INT - 1))
n = (n << 1) | MSB;
```

Left bit rotation of `n` by 1 bit.

You are just shrugging off the MSB but not *adding* it back at LSB position.

Comment: Thanks for answering, what's MSB?

Comment: MSB : most significant bit. LSB : least significant bit. So, MSB and LSB are leftmost and rightmost bit respectively.

Answer (score 0):

use the functions in this link for performing the rotations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift